# How to update a file that I deployed to Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

On deploying my app to Firebase, I am getting this message:

> You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

I learnt from a previous post that I need to replace the default `index.html` with my custom `index.html`. How do I do that using the Firebase Console?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You cannot change hosted files in the Firebase Console.

Instead, you should change the `index.html` on your local copy where you initially ran the `firebase deploy` command. Once you're done with the changes, run `firebase deploy` again to push the updated version of your website to Firebase Hosting.

For small changes it is probably faster to run `firebase serve`. This spins up a local web server, so that you can test the changes. Once you're satisfied they work, publish them to Firebase Hosting with `firebase deploy` again.

**Update**: this is now possible through some custom scripting. See my answer here for details: [Upload single file to firebase hosting via CLI or other without deleting existing ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677351/upload-single-file-to-firebase-hosting-via-cli-or-other-without-deleting-existin)

Comment: Thanks Frank! I clicked on the checkmark but I need more credits to be able to upvote.

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried on console, didn't find any editor so I expected the same. That confirms.

Comment: firebase-serve followed by firebase-deploy seems like the rational answer here

Comment: consider ```firebase deploy --only hosting``` if you only have changed hosting items (and not functions, etc)

Answer (score 3):

Simply make the changes you want to and then type

```
npm run build
```

After this spin the server again using

```
firebase deploy
```

The changes you want will be updated.
You can also see the updated changes with the command

```
firebase serve
```

and then run firebase deploy when you're satisfied.

Comment: I'm able to cross-check it this way, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all Update all the coding and assets files in your local system then,

1) Go to the directory in the terminal by typing $ cd {add your directory}
2) Login on your terminal console by typing $ firebase login in the terminal
3) after login write $ firebase deploy

then, go to Hosting Section in your Firebase Console and delete the previously deployed files by deleting the previously added section in {Poject_Name} release history,

like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9GRt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple solution. This message is caused by the index.html file in your public folder being replaced with the index.html file provided by firebase.
All you have to do is navigate to the directory of your web app folder on your terminal and type in
`$ rm .firebaserc`
then
`$ firebase init`
after you've completed the firebase initialization, replace the new index.html file with the one inside the public folder and then type
`$ firebase deploy`