# How to edit my static site in firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm starting with Firebase Hosting, I made a static website with some Javascript elements. I have a simple question that I did not find clear information in the Firebase documentation: how would I edit my static site? Whether to change some information, or upload a new page? Do I deploy all over again like the first time I uploaded the site?

Comment: Have a look at https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6386780?hl=en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a file that I deployed to Firebase Hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254475/how-to-update-a-file-that-i-deployed-to-firebase-hosting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make changes to a deployed Firebase Hosting website, you should make the necessary changes to your local copy and then run `firebase deploy` again.

Each time you run `firebase deploy` after making a change, the following steps (amongst others) are performed automatically:

- The version number is incremented
- The current version becomes the previous version (and so on)
- All changed files are uploaded
- The changes are made live

This is useful because the full history of your deploys are kept on Firebase Hosting so that you can [rollback to a previous version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying#manage_and_rollback_deploys) should you need to.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, firebase is great.