# Having problems with Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have successfully hosted my page on firebase, however, when it comes to updating the site with new features, I'm struggling.

I have followed the advice on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254475/how-to-update-a-file-that-i-deployed-to-firebase-hosting) but I can't get it to work...

I'm wondering if anyone has a different alternative? At the moment, Im trying:

1. npm run build (to rebuild my file after updates)
2. firebase init
3. Select => Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites
4. Answer: What do you want to use as your public directory? Build
5. Single app? yes
6. firebase deploy

I get this message:

> You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

My problem is that I'm sharing the url with people so they can test it, and as I cant update, I have to redeploy and this will cancel the previous link.

Comment: Can you explain me the detailed steps your doing for each update ? As it seems you repeating the firebase init step again and again for each step.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen differently, and why?  It's not clear what you want to happen other than the deployment of the default content provided by `firebase init`.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, I asked my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478092/having-problems-with-firebase-hosting I'm just hoping to update the hosted page to reflect the changes I make in my document

Comment: I just tried again, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

To make it work I had to delete the existing build file in production, run npm run build and then run firebase deploy. After a few seconds it worked!