# Using Firebase Cloud Functions to Update Hosted File

Tags: firebase, rss, sitemap, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am building a site that is using Angular 4, Firebase, and Firebase Cloud Functions. What I am looking to do is when certain data is added to the database I want to add, remove, or update something in an RSS feed, sitemap, and JSON feed which are files hosted with Firebase Hosting.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this or an alternative if it is not possible without manual updates and redeploys of the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to publish a new (or update a) file to Firebase Hosting based on a database (or other dynamic) trigger.

What *is* possible is to [map a Cloud Function to a path on your site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#directing_hosting_requests_to_your_function) (e.g. `/sitemap` or `/feed`), [generate the HTML in that Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#create_an_http_function_to_your_hosting_site), and then [set caching headers on the result](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#managing_cache_behavior).

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Is it still not possible, now that it is 2022? This S.O. question is the only search result I've found for this, and it's from 2017.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677351/upload-single-file-to-firebase-hosting-via-cli-or-other-without-deleting-existin for an option, although that seems to not be working right now due to a change in the APIs.