# How to implement a sitemap.xml file for a single page app using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, seo, google-cloud-functions, sitemap, firebase-hosting

I was reading Google's guidelines about SEO and I found this.

> **Help Google find your content**
>
> The first step to getting your site on Google is to be sure that Google can find it. The best way to do that is to **submit a sitemap**. A sitemap is a file on your site that tells search engines about new or changed pages on your site. Learn more about how to build and submit a sitemap.

Obs.: My web app is an **ecommerce/blog** in which I have a shop that I have products to sell and I have a blogging section where I create and post content about those products.

So, each product has a **product page**, and each blog post has a **blogPost page**.

Then I went looking for some examples of **Sitemaps** from websites like mine that have good SEO ranking.

And I've found this good example:

**robots.txt**

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: ... // SOME ROUTES

Sitemap: https://www.website.com/sitemap.xml
```

I.E: Apparently the crawler robot finds the Sitemap location from the **robots.txt** file.

And I've also found out that they keep separate sitemap files for blogPost and product pages.

**sitemap.xml**

```
<sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://www.website.com/blogPosts-sitemap.xml</loc> // FOR POSTS
    <lastmod>2019-09-10T05:00:14+00:00</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://www.website.com/products-sitemap.xml</loc>  // FOR PRODUCTS
    <lastmod>2019-09-10T05:00:14+00:00</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

**blogPosts-sitemap.xml**

```
// HUGE LIST WITH AN <url> FOR EACH BLOGPOST URL

<url>
  <loc>
    https://www.website.com/blog/some-blog-post-slug
  </loc>
  <lastmod>2019-09-03T18:11:56.873+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

**products-sitemap.xml**

```
// HUGE LIST WITH AN <url> FOR EACH PRODUCT URL

<url>
  <loc>
    https://www.website.com/gp/some-product-slug
  </loc>
  <lastmod>2019-09-08T07:00:16+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
  <priority>0.3</priority>
</url>
```

**QUESTION**

How can I keep updated `Sitemap` files like that if my web app is a **Single Page App** with client site routing?

Since I'm using Firebase as my hosting, what I've thought about doing is:

**OPTION #1 -  Keep sitemap.xml in Firebase Hosting**

From this question [Upload single file to firebase hosting via CLI or other without deleting existing ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677351/upload-single-file-to-firebase-hosting-via-cli-or-other-without-deleting-existin)

Frank van Puffelen says:

> Update (December 2018): Firebase Hosting now has a REST API. While this still doesn't officially allow you to deploy a single file, you can use it creatively to get what you want. See my Gist here: https://gist.github.com/puf/e00c34dd82b35c56e91adbc3a9b1c412

I could use his Gist to update the `sitemap.xml` file and run this script once a day, or whenever I want. This would work for my current project, but it would not work for a project with a higher change frequency of dynamic pages, like a news portal or market place, for example.

**OPTION #2 - Keep sitemap.xml in Firebase Storage**

Keep the sitemap files in my Storage bucket and update it as frequently as I need via a admin script or a cloud scheduled function.

Set a rewrite in my `firebase.json` and specify a function to respond and serve the sitemap files from the bucket, when requested.

**firebase.json**

```
"hosting": {
 // ...

 // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
 "rewrites": [ {
   "source": "/sitemap.xml",
   "function": "serveSitemapFromStorageBucket"
 } ]
}
```

**FINAL QUESTION**

I'm leaning towards OPTION #2, I want to know if it will work for this specific purpose or if I'm missing something out.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue like you, and wonder if your solution works for google search console?

Comment: @JimmyLin I have a cloud function that generates the `sitemap.xml` on the fly. Ex: `https://www.mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml` will be redirect to a `http` cloud function that will build the file and respond. This way, the sitemap "file" does not exist. It is generated on-demand and it is always updated with the latest data.

Comment: @JimmyLin I've posted an answer.

Comment: We're going in the wrong direction when something this simple, ends up being so complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up creating a cloud function to build the sitemap file on-demand.

**firebase.json**

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/sitemap.xml",
    "function": "buildSitemap"
  },
]
```

**buildSitemap.js** (this is a cloud function)

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

async function buildSitemap(req,res)  {

  // Use firebase-admin to gather necessary data
  // Build the sitemap file string
  // and send it back

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.status(200).send(SITEMAP_STRING);
  return;

}

export default buildSitemap;
```

Comment: Are you still using this method? Because I have a similar approach, however, I feel like there are a few disadvantages with this. You can only store up to 50.000 urls per sitemap, there is a potential for lots of unnecessary reads (I fetch all post ids from Firestore) and lastly, it takes some seconds to create the sitemap each time from scratch.

Comment: I'm still using it. So far it's working fine. I got around 100 urls, though. I know that  you can create a sitemap index and break it into multiple sitemap files, so you get 50k on each one. You can also cache for a day to avoid too many reads.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, I´m currently trying the sitemap-index approach and splitting the urls in several files. I can let you know should I be able to implement it.
One last thing, do you perhaps have a reference or a snippet on how I can cache the sitemap result for a day?

Comment: @LukyFoggy It depends on your implementation details. If your hosting provider has a CDN, you can cache it on the CDN by setting a `Cache-Control: s-maxage=SOME_VALUE_IN_SECONDS` header. Or if you are not behind a CDN, you can cache directly on your server.

Comment: I´m using Firebase Hosting, so adding `res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400');` should do the trick, thank you.

Comment: That's it. You can either set it in the `firebase.json` config file or you can set it on your server / cloud function. Be aware that `firebase.json` will overwrite what you set on your server. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66107249/where-to-set-cache-control-when-using-firebase-hosting-cloud-run-express-serve). At least, those were the results I got after testing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Remove src/sitemap.xml from   angular.json

```
      "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/manifest.json",
          "src/robots.txt"
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `sitemap.xml` inside `public`, `firebase deploy`, and that's it. It works.

If you're coming from `Nuxt.js` question, then I do have a little bonus for you regarding [this comment](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module/issues/227#issuecomment-1457831769), [this commit](https://github.com/Doyban/Doyban-Website/commit/753a939fea3cd63eeac31ed257390177dcb22008) and [this commit](https://github.com/Doyban/Doyban-Website/commit/ec1e2df33f2f640215ecb48a96b11942e646df99). Remember to use `yarn generate`, not `yarn build` before deployment, otherwise the it won't work as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68116649/11127383).