# Where to set Cache-Control when using Firebase Hosting + Cloud Run express server?

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-hosting, cache-control, google-cloud-run

When you are using Firebase Hosting + Cloud Run (express server), Firebase Hosting behaves like a proxy between your client and your server.

Where should I set my `Cache-Control` header?

- In `firebase.json` to configure Firebase Hosting
- Or should I use `res.set("Cache-Control")` in my express server over on Cloud Run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it both ways. But whatever you set on `firebase.json` will overwrite what you set on your `express` code.

For example: the [default](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#set_cache-control) `Cache-Control` on Firebase Hosting is `private`.

[image]

For example, if you don't add any `Cache-Control` to your `firebase.json` and you add `res.set("Cache-Control","no-cache");` to your express response, your response will be `no-cache`, as you intended.

But if at the same time your add something like this to your `firebase.json`, it will overwrite your `res.set()` call:

```
{
  "source": "/**",
  "headers": [{
    "key": "Cache-Control",
    "value": "public"           // OR EVEN IF YOU EXPLICITLY SET "private", WHICH IS THE DEFAULT
  }]                            // IT WILL OVERWRITE WHAT YOU SET ON YOUR SERVER WITH res.set() 
}
```