# Dynamically generate sitemap using @nuxtjs/sitemap

Tags: nuxt.js, sitemap

I am using [@nuxtjs/sitemap](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/) as my sitemap generator, some of the routes are given by ajax.

I need it to have latest api data whenever someone visit /sitemap.xml, is it possible to do it with this library?

My config here in nuxt.config.js:

```js
{
  sitemap: {
    defaults: {
      lastmod: new Date(),
    },
    routes: async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
      )
      return data.map((post) => `/posts/${post.id}`)
    },

    cacheTime: 1,
  },
}
```

When I activate my server and visit /sitemap.xml,

it shows the latest routes with correct lastmod,

but after that it won't update again,

how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup [looks fine](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/usage/sitemap-options#from-a-function-which-returns-a-promise) and this is working great so far, the thing is that the sitemap is probably created during build time.
So, if:

- `target: static` >> `yarn generate && yarn start`
- `target: server` (default) >> `yarn build && yarn start`

This should work fine in real world scenario tho, because you'll push some fresh code to your hosting platform, and it will build your new app.
Hence it'll create the new updated sitemap.

---

It may also come from the fact that the default [`cacheTime`](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/usage/sitemap-options/#cachetime-optional---number) is set to 15min. Maybe try to change this to something smaller.

---

Is your website supposed to have dynamically moving parts without a new build, so like depending on a highly dynamic API or alike?
If it's the case, maybe look for this Github issue: https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module/issues/186

Comment: Mr.kissu I think I figured it out. It happened because I stupidly set default: { lastmod: new Date() }, in my case I should wrap lastmod into axios call

Comment: e.g., 
return data.map((post) => ({
        url: `/posts/${post.id}`,
        lastmod: new Date(),
      }))

Comment: Thank a lot, the `yarn generate`, instead of `yarn build` was crucial for me.